# Combining these two SQL statements into one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What would be the best way to combine these two SQL statements into one? I tried using union, but seem to be going nowhere.

```
select id as id from likes where type=1;

select sum(votes) as votes from likes where parent=id;
```

Here is the `likes` table:

```
id  type  parent  country  votes
 1     1       0       US      0
 2     2       1       US      6 // This +
19     3       1       US      3 // This
 3     3       2       US      3
 7     3       2       US      3
 4    10       3       US      1
 5    10       3       US      1
 6    10       3       US      1
10    10       7       US      1
 9    10       7       US      1
 8    10       7       US      1
20    10      19       US      1
21    10      19       US      1
22    10      19       US      1
```

This is the result I'm trying to achieve:

```
id | votes
---------------
1  | 9
```

Comment: They do different things.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've updated the question with the table and what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  l1.id,
  SUM(l2.votes) AS Totalvotes
FROM likes AS l1
INNER JOIN likes AS l2 ON l1.id = l2.parent 
WHERE l1.type = 1 
GROUP BY l1.id;
```

See it in action here:

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/132fe/1)

This will give you:

```
| ID | TOTALVOTES |
-------------------
|  1 |          9 |
```

Comment: Your solution gives me each and every row.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. This works well. One small thing, before I go, If I need to specify another where condition, where do I do it? Like this: `WHERE l1.type =1 and l1.country = 'us'`?

Comment: @Norman - Yes, like this `WHERE l1.type =1 and l1.country = 'us'`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/132fe/2

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(votes) AS votes 
FROM likes 
WHERE parent IN (SELECT id FROM likes WHERE type=1)
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem, I believe:

```
SELECT parent AS id, SUM(votes) AS votes FROM likes WHERE parent IN (SELECT id FROM likes WHERE type = 1) GROUP BY parent;
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't wrap my mind around the question hard enough. The updated answer *should* work, although I can't really test it right now.

Comment: Works now. Just a bit of testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
select id,sum(votes) as votes from likes where type=1 and parent=id;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It wouldn't work because you will be operating within the same line, i.e. you are literally looking for rows where parent and id are equal. You need to use either a subquery or a join on the same table - no avoiding it.